# How to pass Laravel $request->file(...) directly to Guzzle POST request

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

How can I pass the `$request->file(...)` to `Guzzle` thru POST request? 
**Or is it even possible?** Should I upload it first?

This is my attempt:

```
$client = new Client([ 'base_uri' => 'http://api.domain.com']);
$response = $client->post(
        '/api/dosomething',
        [
            'multipart' => [
                [
                  'Content-type' => 'multipart/form-data',
                  'name' => 'photo_1',
                  'contents' => $request->file('photo_1')
                ]
            ]
         ]
);
```

This is not working. The response body is just blank.

Comment: $response = $request->send(); ?

Comment: @AhmedAboud no it is already sent if I use the post method. It is working already if I will just send normal texts.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution below (We need to specify the path of the temporary file in the temp folder with the code `$file->getPathName()`):

```
$client = new Client([ 'base_uri' => 'http://api.domain.com']);
$file = $request->file('photo_1')
$response = $client->post(
        '/api/dosomething',
        [
            'multipart' => [
                [
                  'Content-type' => 'multipart/form-data',
                  'name' => 'photo_1',
                  'contents' => fopen($file->getPathName(), 'r')
                ]
            ]
         ]
);
```